# how to sync/backup user data to the cloud and access it from desktop?

Tags: android, cloud

I`m planning to build an Android app for which I want to sync/backup user data to the cloud. I want the user to be able to open my app in Android, make some changes to its data, and, when they open the desktop version of this app, all the data they changes will there too. That should work both ways.

Which is the best option for storing this data? Is there any free option? Considering the data are user specific, and that a user won't be able to access the data from another user.

I did a little search and found out about Google Cloud storage. It has a free plan, but I don't know if it will be enough.

Comment: You will have to set up your own server to store the data you require. And then you have to build the Android app and Desktop app to link to the same server, therefore the data will be synced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for a [MBaaS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_backend_as_a_service). This [article](http://waracle.net/how-to-choose-the-right-backend-as-a-service-baas-platform/) outlines a few options you have out there. Consider using [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/) as well, since it's backed by Google.

Comment: That seems to solve my problem. I won't be implementing this now, I'm just probing for a future project. As I use and implement, I'll comeback to this post to give feedback.